# How to enable httpCompression/scheme as deflate at site level inside web.config in IIS10

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-10

I am trying to enable dynamic compression "deflate" at site level i.e. web.config for each application in IIS 10.

Dynamic compression is already enabled at both server and site level.

Also, httpcompression override setting is also set already as "overrideModeDefault="Allow"":

After adding "application/json" as dynamic type at site level, gzip compression is working for me. Gzip seems to be working as it is already added at server level by default.
I need to make changes for deflate as well at site level only but not working for me.

I have tried troubleshooting using "failed requests using tracing" feature in IIS10 but getting "NO_MATCHING_SCHEME" when sending "Accept-Encoding" request header as "deflate".

Upon setting the scheme name as "deflate" at server level(applicationhost.config) , it is working fine. However, not working when trying to add it at site level(web.config) instead.
As read before that httpcompression override at site level is now available with IIS 10 but does not seem to be the case with "scheme" .
Could anyone please advise me in this.
Appreciate the help please!
Thank you.

Need to enable "deflate" dynamic compression at site level only.

Comment: Certain settings are not flipped by changes in configuration files but in IIS module source code (I know of several examples). So, very likely you hit such a case and cannot achieve what you wanted.

Comment: @LexLi thank you for your response. Just need to ask as if we can expect deflate dynamic compression to be working for any application by adding
"<scheme name="deflate" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>" at site web.config level only ? 
As it is working fine when adding this configuration at server applicationHost.config level, but need it to be working application specific please.
Appreciate your valuable inputs please.
Thank you.

Comment: Hope you understand that your careful experiments can only take us this far. To confirm this is by design and/or learn whether any workaround, you need access to the actual IIS source code or a support ticket through Microsoft Support.